# Prenex form of uniqueness quantifier

Tags: first-order-logic

$\exists !xP(x)$ is generally defined as $$\exists x(P(x)\land\forall y(P(y)\rightarrow y=x)).$$

What is the prenex normal form of this? I think it should be $\exists x\forall y(P(x)\land (P(y)\rightarrow y=x)).$ If so, how to prove this (*using only the prenex conversion rules*)?

Comment: Correct. See [Prenex Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conjunction_and_disjunction) : $(\forall x\phi )\land \psi$  is equivalent to $\forall x(\phi \land \psi )$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But wouldn’t that be true only when $\phi$ and $\psi$ have no common free variables (which is not the case here)?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So you’re saying that $P(x)\land\forall y(P(y)\rightarrow y=x)$ is equivalent to $\forall y(P(x)\land (P(y)\rightarrow y=x))$? That seems incorrect.

Comment: To me it seems more correct to say $\forall y(P(x)\land (P(y)\rightarrow y=x’))$.

Comment: But that is not what we need. We need : "there is an $x$ that is $P$ and every $y$ that is $P$ is equal to **that** $x$".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yeah, that makes sense intuitively. But how to show that formally?

Answer (score 1):

Correct.

See in general [Prenex Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conjunction_and_disjunction) for the equivalences requested for prenex operations, that hold in general provided that $x$ is not *free* in $ψ$.

More specifically : $(∀xϕ) ∧ ψ$ is equivalent to $∀x(ϕ ∧ ψ)$.

The proof relies on the proof system used; it is quite straightforward with [Natural Deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7)

A semantic argument may help : let $D$ a non-empty domain. Several cases :

*(i)* let $a \in D$ such that $Pa$ is False. Thus, $Pa \land \forall y Qy$ is False.

But also $Pa \land Qb$ is False, for every $b \in D$. Thus $\forall y(Pa \land Qy)$ is False.

*(ii)* let $a \in D$ such that $Pa$ is True. Two sub-cases :

*(ii-a)* $Qb$ is True for every element $b \in D$. Thus $\forall y Qy$ holds in $D$ and thus $Pa \land \forall y Qy$ is True.

But also $Pa \land Qb$ holds, for every $b \in D$. Thus : $\forall y(Pa \land Qy)$ is True.

*(ii-b)* $Qb$ is False for some element $b \in D$. Thus $\forall y Qy$ is False and also $Pa \land \forall y Qy$ is False.

But then $Pa \land Qb$ is False, and thus $\forall y(Pa \land Qy)$ is False.